# Postgres query help regarding max creation_time and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I've a complicated scenario that I just can't get my head around. 
So we have a Postgres db which normalized.

Image one Query

```
select id, rule_id, status, risk_level, creationtime, cloudaccount_id, organization_id, description,
       reg_id, pro_id, function_id, category_id, group_id, resource_id

from risk_child
```

Image 2 Query

```
select ser_id, creationtime, cloud_account_id, owner_id, reg_id, organization_id, pro_id, record_creation_time
       resource_id
from resource
```

The challenge is that we have field called `Rules` and each `Rule` will have multiple `resource` we want to trigger a query that will give us latest entries in our `risk_child` table based on single rule with multiple resources.

I've come across one query but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
select rc.id,rc.resource_id,max(rc.creationtime)as "create_date_time",rl.rule_tag,rc.status,rc.risk_level,
       rc.user_id,rc.cloudaccount_id,rc.organization_id,rc.description,r.region,
       p.provider,f.function_name,c.category_name,g.group_name,rc.signature_status
from risk_child rc, resource rs,category c, function f , g_by g,
     provider p, region r, rule rl,service s
where rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id and c.id  = rc .category_id and 
      rc.function_id = f.id and rc.group_id = g.id and rc.pro_id = p.id and rc.rule_id = rl.id and
      rc.reg_id = r.id and s.id = rs.ser_id and rc.rule_id >=145 and 
      (rc.creationtime in(select max(creationtime) from risk_child group by resource_id) or 
      rc.creationtime in (select max(creationtime) from risk_child group by rule_id))

group by rc.creationtime,rl.rule_tag,rc.status,rc.risk_level,
       rc.user_id,rc.cloudaccount_id,rc.organization_id,rc.description,r.region,
       p.provider,f.function_name,c.category_name,g.group_name,rc.id,rc.resource_id,rc.signature_status
order by rc.id asc
```

The output doesn't give us the latest record based on `creationtime` in `risk_child`

[Result of Query # 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvTVM.png)

[Result of Query # 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7980.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer Edited*

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (rc.resource_id, rc.rule_id) MAX(rc.creationtime) as creationtime, rc.resource_id, rl.rule_tag, s.service, r.region,
       rc.status, rs.vpc_id, rc.cloudaccount_id, rc.organization_id, rs.owner_id, rc.description, 
       f.function_name, g.group_name, rc.risk_level, rc.id, rc.user_id, rc.pro_id, c.category_name

FROM risk_child rc, resource rs, rule rl, service s, region r, function f, g_by g, category c
WHERE rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id AND rl.id = rc.rule_id  AND s.id = rs.ser_id AND rs.reg_id = r.id AND 
      f.id = rc.function_id AND c.id = rc.category_id AND g.id = rc.group_id
      AND rc.cloudaccount_id like any (array${modifiedCloudAccounts}) AND rc.organization_id=${orgId}
      AND rc.rule_id > 0
GROUP BY rc.rule_id, rc.creationtime, rc.creationtime,rc.resource_id,rl.rule_tag, rl.id, s.service, r.region, rc.status,
         rs.vpc_id, rc.cloudaccount_id, rc.organization_id, rs.owner_id, rc.description, f.function_name,
         g.group_name, rc.risk_level, rc.id, rc.user_id, rc.pro_id, c.category_name
ORDER BY rc.resource_id, rc.rule_id ASC
```

Okay so this query worked for me. 
I had to put two columns in `DISTINCT ON` and I got the data I needed !

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't know that ! 
I've edited and added the actual Answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want a to-many relationship fetch where only the newest target object is shown for each source object. As a rule, `GROUP BY` requests are not suitable for this. In my opinion, a `GROUP BY` clause that refers to an aggregate column does not make sense either.

But `DISTINCT ON` makes this relatively easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(rs.resource_id) rs.resource_id, rc.creation_time, ...
FROM resource rs JOIN risk_child rc ON rs.resource_id = rc.resource_id ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY rs.resource_id, rc. rc.creation_time DESC, ...
```

The `DISTINCT ON` clause ensures that each resource occurs only once in the result. For it to always be the latest risk child, you must sort by `creation_time`, but Postgres also requires you to sort by the columns in `DISTINCT ON` in this case.

Comment: Yes, as in `source-object` => Rule and it would have multiple `target-objects` such as resources.

Comment: ```
select DISTINCT ON(rc.resource_id) rc.id, rc.creationtime as "create_date_time",rl.rule_tag, . . .
where rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id and c.id  = rc .category_id and 
      rc.function_id = f.id . . . 
order by rc.resource_id, rc.creationtime,rl.rule_tag,rc.status,rc.risk_level,
       rc.user_id . . . 
        DESC
 ```

Comment: I did what you suggested. but stilll getting repeated data.

Comment: The query in my answer is only a scheme how to `DISTINCT ON`queries. Unfortunately your query is very complex and hard to understand. Can you reduce the complexity of your query?

Comment: ```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (rc.resource_id) MAX(rc.creationtime), rc.resource_id, rl.rule_tag, s.service, r.region,rc.status, rs.vpc_id
FROM risk_child rc, resource rs, rule rl, service s, region r
WHERE rc.resource_id = rs.resource_id AND rl.id = rc.rule_id  AND s.id = rs.ser_id AND rs.reg_id = r.id 
   AND rc.cloudaccount_id='Q4wBhFLFYuJbnn3O0HLU' AND rc.organization_id='atompoint_z1px2'
   AND rc.rule_id >= 0
GROUP BY rc.creationtime,rc.resource_id,rl.rule_tag, rl.id, s.service, r.region, rc.status, rs.vpc_id, rc.cloudaccount_id, rc.organization_id
ORDER BY rc.resource_id ASC

```

Comment: The above query gives me perfect result for a single `rule` but I can't get all rules when doing something like `rc.rule_id >= 0`

Comment: I think combining `DISTINCT ON` with `GROUP BY` will not lead the desired result. Grouping is for building aggregates, but you want to select a row with a _maximal_ element from a set of rows.
The SQL statements in your comments are unreadable.